# Facing Issue On Passing Hex Color on PHP imagecolorallocate()

Tags: php

I am trying to create an image in PHP but use Hex color instead of RGB in `imagecolorallocate()` function but I am getting this error message:

> Warning: imagecolorallocate() expects exactly 4 parameters, 2 given

can you please let me know how to fix this?

```
<?php
$dir = "maps/";

function hex2rgb($hex) {
   $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

   if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
   } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
   }
   $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
   //return implode(",", $rgb);
   return $rgb; 
}
$rgb = hex2rgb("#cc0");
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, $rgb);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
// Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
imagejpeg($im, $dir.'image_demo.jpg');

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imagecolorallocate expects four parameters an **image**, **R**ed value, **G**reen value, and **B**lue value. You're only passing an image and an array representing these colors.

Try:

```
  imagecolorallocate($im, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
```

[Read more about imagecolorallocate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)